# In apex, how to replace the value in the string

Tags: apex, lightning

**This is my test code**

```
String soqlStr = '1 OR 2 AND 3';

List<String> strList = new List<String>();
strList.add('Name = a');
strList.add('City = b');
strList.add('Birthdate__c = c');
String s2 = '';

for (Integer i = 0; i < strList.size() ; i ++) {

    String s1 = strList[i];
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 's1 = ' + s1);

    s2 = soqlStr.replace(String.valueOf(i+1), s1);
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 's2 = ' + s2);
}
```

**I want to get the result:**

```
String soqlStr = 'Name = a OR City = b AND Birthdate__c = c';
```

[image]

Comment: don't you want `Name IN ('a','b','c')` ? or why not use apex bind variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specifically for your case - Derek's answer is absolutely correct. But in the general case, if we want to build a string by substitution the certain slots with arguments, it is convenient to use [`String.format()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) method:

> **public static String** format(**String** stringToFormat, List<**Object**>
>   formattingArguments);
>
> Treat the first argument as a pattern and return
>   a string using the second argument for substitution and formatting.
>   The substitution and formatting are the same as `apex:outputText` and
>   the Java `MessageFormat` class. Non-string types in the second
>   argument’s List are implicitly converted to strings, respecting the
>   `toString()` method overrides that exist on the type.

```
String template = '{0} OR {1} AND {2}';
List<String> params = new List<String>();
params.add('Name = a');
params.add('City = b');
params.add('Birthdate__c = c');
String formattedTemplate = String.format(template, params);
/* String formattedTemplate = 'Name = a OR City = b AND Birthdate__c = c'; */
```

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you very much.
But I still have a problem, after using [String.format], the last parameter never changes.
Result: template2 = City = b OR Birthdate__c = c AND {3}

Comment: I've updated indexes in my answer, starting from 0. Check again, please. Just a typo

Comment: I understand, thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're trying to do things the hard way. SOQL provides a built-in way to do this using `IN`.

ex.

```
List<String> accountNames = new List<String>{'Tech co', 'MegaCorp, utld.', 'Mom \'n Pop Shop'};
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name IN :accountNames];
```

If this is for a dynamic query, you might have to do a little more work, but a little ingenuity with `String.join()` should get you where you need to go in that case (still using the `IN` keyword)

Comment: Sorry, I did not express it clearly. I updated the question, can you help me again?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to store a list of conditions and add them to a soql query you can try `String.join(strList, ' OR ');`.